# prevent duplicates of multiplefields with index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

My document:

```
{
    "age":"20",
    "name":"leandro"
}
```

I need prevent inserting new documents if another exists with same age and email.
Can I do this using index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it by creating index with unique=true as follows. After creating index, if you try to insert a document with same age & name then you will get duplicate key exception.

```
db.myObject.ensureIndex({age:1, name:1}, {unique : true})
```

For details you can read [Create a Unique Index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) document.

Comment: will this compare each field, or both fields?

Comment: This will throw exception if both age & name is same. Otherwise it inserts new document.

Comment: thanks, i'll try it. another question: can I enable sharding with this index?

Comment: AFAIK, you should have an index that starts with shard key. If you create an index that starts with shard key I think it should work but I am not %100 sure. It will be better to ask this as a separate question.